# Create a role and grant privileges to that role

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The main purpose is to create separate roles like developers, testers and others to have individual logins to the oracle database. Currently, there is no monitoring and using the same credentials an application is using to query which makes really hard to monitor what changes are made and who made those.

1. create role developers
2. grant privileges like insert, delete, update, select ... to developers(role)
3. create users
4. grant role to users
5. Assign the tablespaces to access individually to user with those privileges.

I tried to assign all tables to role but it's not working.

```
begin
    for x in (select object_name from all_objects where owner='app_owner' and object_type in ('TABLE','VIEW')) loop
        execute immediate 'GRANT select on app_owner.' || x.object_name || ' to developers';
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Above SQL is not granting privileges to the role (developers). However, if I do the grant individually it is fine.

```
grant use of tablespace <tablespacename> to role;
```

Tried above still no use. 
Any thoughts on how to accomplish the above requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot grant use of a tablespace to a ROLE.  The users would need quota on the tablespace to create objects in the tablespace.  You grant quota on the CREATE USER or via an ALTER USER command.  I do not see the error in the posted PL/SQL to issue the grant but do not have time to edit and test the code.  If you query dba_tab_privs for the role do you see grants to it?  Did you remember to grant the role to the target users?  HTH -- Mark D Powell --

Comment: I do not see the grants in dba_tab_privs to grant users. The sql is executed fine but no grants are reflected.

Comment: The grantee in `dba_tab_privs` will be the user or role to which the privilege was granted. If you grant `select` on some table to a role, it will only list that role as the grantee and not the users who currently have that role granted to them and currently enabled. I'm still not clear what is "not working".

Answer (score 0):

Code you wrote is *close*, but not *close enough* - letter case matters.

```
                                                        THIS!
                                                        vvvvv
SQL> select object_name from all_objects where owner = 'scott' and object_type in ('TABLE', 'VIEW');

no rows selected

SQL> select object_name from all_objects where owner = 'SCOTT' and object_type in ('TABLE', 'VIEW');

OBJECT_NAME
------------------------------
V_SALGRADE
V_DEPT
V_BONUS
DEPT
EMP_VIEW_UPDT
EMP
```